# Will Stripe Payment Processor work with CiviCRM 4.6 and/or Drupal Webforms?

Tags: webform-civicrm, payment-processor, stripe

We are planning to use stripe payment processor with CiviCRM 4.6.x and are considering using it in Drupal Webforms. Currently the extension is only marked as compatible with 4.5 but there is a 4.6 dev branch on github.

I was looking into stripe in combination with CiviCRM <--> Drupal webforms and found that there had been issues, described [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2225627) and [here](https://github.com/drastik/com.drastikbydesign.stripe/issues/42). I was however not sure if those were resolved (as indicated by the Drupal issue) or if there are still problems as the Github issue is still open.

I tried to contact Drastik on the [stripe payment processor blog](http://drastikbydesign.com/blog-entry/civicrm-stripe-payment-processor) but the spam protection wouldn't allow me for some reason. I also tried the contact form and email but got no response.

I would love to get some feedback on 4.6 compatibility from the developer or anyone who has tried it.

Answer (score 4):

We are using Stripe with 4.4.14 and had problems accepting payments for memberships using a webform. With investigation though, our developer installed a version of Stripe 1.9.1 from the github and the latest dev build of webform and it is now working for us.

Whether anything within 4.5/4.6 has changed to make our experience irrelevant, that I can not answer.

Whether it is useful or not, contrary to the information on some of the links you provide indicating it might be a problem with the webform module; in our case it was apparently the Stripe module that was the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I will let you know how things go with 4.6 & Stripe.

Answer (score 4):

We use Stripe with CiviCRM 4.6.4 on Drupal 7's latest rev and are not having issues.  We grabbed the latest Civi Stripe library from github.

So far we have only processed event registrations, not membership payments or other contributions.  We haven't tried processing payments via WebForms, only regular civicrm event registration pages.

We had one issue where the Stripe library would not be made available if other payment processors or the "pay later" option was available on that event.  With that one issue aside, we've had no problems and are enjoying using Stripe with Civi.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. As we need the pay later function, I will probably simply try it out and let everyone know how it went

Answer (score 4):

As promised, here are our experiences with Stripe Version 1.9.1 | CiviCRM 4.6.8 | Drupal 7:

- We are using it on CiviCRM contribution pages for memberships
- In order for the pay later option to work we needed to fix an issue
- Afaik the fix has not been integrated with the Stripe master branch - our version can been found [here](https://github.com/systopia/com.drastikbydesign.stripe).
- Apart from the pay later problem everything worked really smoothly
- We have not tried using stripe within an CiviCRM Webform